# Create own NotificationStyle

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

In my Android application I want to create a expendable notification. For this I have to set a Style for the notification like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
builder.setContentTitle("My notification");
builder.setContentText("Hello World!");

builder.setStyle(...);
```

Android gives me some styles I can use with this method but I like to create my own, so I can load a layout in the notification. So how can I do this? If I create a subclass of `Style` there are only these two methods:

```
public Notification build();
public void setBuilder(Builder builder);
```

So how can I load my own layout in the notification? `builder.setContent` is insufficient for me because then I only have 64dp for the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this problem. It's really easy. Just use this code here:

```
String packageName = this.getPackageName();
RemoteViews bigView = new RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.test);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
builder.setContentTitle("My notification");
builder.setContentText("Hello World!");

Notification noti = builder.build();
noti.bigContentView = bigView;

NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mgr.notify(1234, noti);
```